# Razor Pages - Model binding complex object to route parameter issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a fairly trivial route template setup for my page in Asp.Net Core.

```
@page "/Meetings"
```

Along with this, I have a form setup to post some values

```
 <form method="post">
        <input asp-for="PageParameters.PageSize" />
        @if (Model.XPaginationDto.PreviousPageLink != null)
        {
            <button type="submit" asp-route-pageNum="@(Model.XPaginationDto.CurrentPage - 1)" class="btn btn-dark text-light">Previous</button>
        }
        @for (var i = 1; i <= Model.XPaginationDto.TotalPages; i++)
        {
            <button type="submit" asp-route-pageNum="@i" class="btn btn-dark text-light">@i</button>
        }
</form>
```

I have a complex object in my PageModel setup as below. Note that I have set  `[BindProperties(SupportsGet = true)]` on my PageModel so that I can paginate even when users are doing get requests.

```
 public class PageParametersDto
    {
        public int PageNum { get; set; } = 1;
        public int PageSize { get; set; } = 2;
        public string Filters { get; set; }
        public string Sorts { get; set; }
    }
```

When the form gets posted, the PageSize property is correctly bound as the input uses the `asp-for` Attribute. The PageNum property is not bound though. That is surprising because model binding looks for form, route, and query data to bind properties.

The PageNum property is being set at the route parameter level. When it's posted back, it does not work.

I.e. when I try to redirect to the page with the parameters, it does not bind the PageNum property.

```
return RedirectToPage("/Meetings", new { PageParameters.PageNum, PageParameters.PageSize });
```

I can certainly do below:

```
public IActionResult OnPost(int? PageNum)
        {

            return RedirectToPage("/Meetings", new { PageNum, PageParameters.PageSize });
        }
```

When the redirect occurs, on the GET request both parameters are bound correctly. How is it that the form post cannot do the same thing?

I have already researched this on https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-complex-collections. None of the examples explain how to bind complex objects to route parameters.